# How to solve javascript "Unhandled Promise Rejection" and "Property 'p' doesn't exist" errors?

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I'm working on a game using spark ar, by following the tutorial from youtube (blinking game tutorial).
apparently when I was working there was an error in the script

```js
    const Scene = require('Scene');
    export const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');
    const Patches = require("Patches");

    Promise.all([
        Scene.root.findFirst('number'),]).then(onReady);

    function onReady(assets) {
      var counterNumber = assets[0];
      var scoreNumber = p.outputs.getScalar("score");

      scoreNumber.then(e => {
        e.monitor().subscribe(value => {
          counterNumber.text = value.newValue.toString();
        });
      });
    }
```

Error : Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Property 'p' doesn't exist

Comment: where is `p` defined?

Comment: I don't know because I just followed the tutorial

Comment: What tutorial? May you share that?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDI6xi9z3Zk&list=PLUn_zuDxW8B7EVD8hvtLaVZJcuf2Lc0ka&index=2

Comment: And that outputs JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a const P as below  and check whether its working or not

```
const Scene = require('Scene');
const P = require('Patches');
```

reference taken from [Score Didnt show up (Spark AR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092594/score-didnt-show-up-spark-ar)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is on this line :

```
var scoreNumber = p.outputs.getScalar("score");
```

"p" is not defined anywhere in your entire code that's why it is throwing error

Comment: I don't know because I just followed the tutorial